# Por que falla este código

Tags: html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Password</th>
      <th scope="col">Warranty expiration date</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="table-light" id="table_0">
<td>test@test.com</td><td>1234</td>
<td>12/16/2018</td>
<td id="msg_0"></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="CheckAccount("test@test.com", "0");" class="btn btn-warning">Check account</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de cambiar las comillas dobles por simples dentro del onclick asi:

```js
function CheckAccount(email, val) {
  console.log(email);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Password</th>
      <th scope="col">Warranty expiration date</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="table-light" id="table_0">
<td>test@test.com</td><td>1234</td>
<td>12/16/2018</td>
<td id="msg_0"></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="CheckAccount('test@test.com', '0');" class="btn btn-warning">Check account</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Gracias, Me imaginaba que ese podría ser el posible problema. Como trabajo también con php pues el tema de las comillas en una putada :v. Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

No has cerrado la etiqueta table, no obstante el error es del javascript que tendra algun error de sintaxis como que falta un { o algo asi.

Comment: Ummm suena a opinión; asegura o modifica la última parte

Comment: pues las respuestas deben ser exactas, para que quien consulta sepa como corregir el fallo